# Replace partial value inside row

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a database table in wordpress that has been imported from a Movable Type CMS so it's not perfect.

- Table: wp_posts
- Column: post_content

Inside post_content is the entire blog post, and in some cases they contain inline images with a URL, such as:

```
    ...post content...<img src="http://url.com/images/image1.jpg"/>...content
    ...post content...<img src="http://url.com/image2.jpg"/>...content
```

I'm trying to make ALL the urls point to `http://url.com/images/`

Currently I have this as my SQL query, which works when only when the path is NOT `url.com/images`, which it turns into `url.com/images/images/`:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'url.com','url.com/images')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%url.com%';
```

Is there any way to run a single query and update all necessary rows to be the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to convert your existing URLs to something else, run the original query, and then revert them all back again.

This query will replace all instances of `url.com/images` to `[PLACEHOLDER]`.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'url.com/images','[PLACEHOLDER]')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%url.com/images%';
```

Now run your original query to append `/images` to the `url.com`:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'url.com','url.com/images')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%url.com%';
```

And now you're free to move the `[PLACEHOLDER]` back:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'[PLACEHOLDER]','url.com/images')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%[PLACEHOLDER]%';
```

All in one lump, for copy & paste ease:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'url.com/images','[PLACEHOLDER]')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%url.com/images%';
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'url.com','url.com/images')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%url.com%';
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'[PLACEHOLDER]','url.com/images')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%[PLACEHOLDER]%';
```

Comment: That works! I was trying to avoid doing multiples queries, but this is still pretty easy.

Comment: Glad it worked.  You can probably do it in a single query with the help of a bit of regexp, but simplicity is often preferential.

Comment: I did think about doing a regexp, but I'm just using phpMyAdmin on a locally installed wordpress instance, and there didn't seem to be any easy way to do that either. The native support for regex is lacking in SQL as far as I could tell.